# VSTS Associating build definitions with build templates

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to control the changes to several build definitions in VSTS using the Build Template feature. However I can't seem to find a way to link/associate build definitions to a build template (Eg: Like Team City does). Basically I want to be able to modify the template and let that change propagate to all the linked build definitions.

Any one has achieved this?

Are there any workarounds to achieving this in VSTS?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, modifying build templates is not available in VSTS (let alone applying the changed build template to related build definitions).

But there has an user voice [Allow editing of existing build definition templates](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33837349-allow-editing-of-existing-build-definition-templat) which suggests the feature to modify build templates. You can vote and follow up.

And the workaround for now is delete and recreate the build template, and then you can create new build definitions by selecting the recreate build template. Or you should update the existing build definitions manually.

Comment: Is there a similar user voice for linking templates to builds that you are aware of?

Comment: @Uchitha Build template can only be select during new build definition creating. Existing build definition can not be updated automatically based on a build template. And there has no such user voice for now, while you can post an user voice with your idea :)

Comment: Done - https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34042840-vsts-associate-build-templates-with-build-defini